# opencart getcategories function goes into infinite loop

Tags: e-commerce, opencart

I have an opencart shop with around 1300 categories and i'm not able to insert a new category or edit the existing category. I have installed pagination function, but it speeds up only category view. i did some debugging and found that the below function goes into an infinite loop once i click insert or edit inside the admin panel. Can anyone help me how to fix this

```
public function getCategories($parent_id = 0) {
        $category_data = $this->cache->get('category.' . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . '.' . (int)$parent_id);

        if (!$category_data) {
            $category_data = array();

            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category c LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category_description cd ON (c.category_id = cd.category_id) WHERE c.parent_id = '" . (int)$parent_id . "' AND cd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' ORDER BY c.sort_order, cd.name ASC");

            foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
                $category_data[] = array(
                    'category_id' => $result['category_id'],
                    'name'        => $this->getPath($result['category_id'], $this->config->get('config_language_id')),
                    'status'      => $result['status'],
                    'sort_order'  => $result['sort_order']
                );

                $category_data = array_merge($category_data, $this->getCategories($result['category_id']));
            }   

            $this->cache->set('category.' . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . '.' . (int)$parent_id, $category_data);
        }

        return $category_data;
    }
```

Comment: At what point in the above does it start looping? Can you stick in some echo statements to see how far you get?

Comment: echo doesn't work as this dosen't get over...In the array_merge, i becomes recursive and it goes into subcategories... so in my server it shows 500 internal error and in my local server it shows timeout.. Also i doesn't reach till the cache set function...

Comment: So are you saying that the recursion occurs in `$category_data = array_merge($category_data, $this->getCategories($result['category_id']));` is this correct? If so before it echo, or var_dump, out the values for $category_data and $result['category_id']

Answer (score 1):

**First Solution:**
Do you also have Category Descriptions in database? If so, these so many descriptions being loaded by MySQL may be making burden over server. Try optimize the Query, select only required columns, you may change query as under:
`$query = $this->db->query("SELECT c.category_id, cd.name FROM ...`

**Second Solution**
You can do one more debug trick which once solved my problem. Add an echo statement:

```
echo $result['name'];
$category_data = array_merge($category_data, $this->getCategories($result['category_id']));` `
```

This way you'll get to know the exact location of the category where process gets hanged. There may be some problem with that particular category only.

**Third Solution**
Try changing

`'name'        => $this->getPath($result['category_id'], $this->config->get('config_language_id')),`

To:

`'name'        => $result['name'],`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have a current but not permanent solution that worked for me... I dont know whether it's the right way to do, but it works for me.I changed the query to this

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category c ORDER BY c.parent_id,c.sort_order");
```

And commented off

```
//$category_data = array_merge($category_data, $this->getCategories($result['category_id']));
```

This currently works for me, but i don't know whether it's the correct way or not. Thanks for the quick help everyone.